# pyspark , principle of worker.py and daemon.py?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Can [worker.py](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/worker.py) work alone without [daemon.py](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/daemon.py)?

The daemon.py is first started . And the daemon.py manages the worker.py. In a spark application with more than two shuffle operation, After one shuffle ,what will happen to daemon.py and worker.py?

Comment: worker.py Can work alone without daemon.py. daemon.py is for effiency

Comment: Spark create a worker.py when `compute` method of PythonRDD.scala is called and then destroy it after the `END_OF_STREAM` signal